# How to do PCA and SVM for classification in python

Tags: python, classification, svm, pca

I am doing classification, and I have a list with two sizes like this;

```
Data=[list1,list2]
```

list1 is *1000*784* size. It means that 1000 images the have been reshaped from *28*28* size into *784*.

list2 is *1000*1* size. It shows the label that each images is belonged to.
With the below code, I applied PCA:

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
results = PCA(Data[0])
```

the output is like this:

```
Out[40]: <matplotlib.mlab.PCA instance at 0x7f301d58c638>
```

now, I want to use SVM as classifier. 
I should add the labels. So I have the new data like this for SVm:

```
newData=[results,Data[1]]
```

I do not know how use SVM here.

Comment: You could use the package from sklearn to do the feature reduction and classifier training.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import cross_validation

Data=[list1,list2]
X = Data[0]
y = Data[1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)# adjust yourself
pca.fit(X_train)
X_t_train = pca.transform(X_train)
X_t_test = pca.transform(X_test)
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_t_train, y_train)
print 'score', clf.score(X_t_test, y_test)
print 'pred label', clf.predict(X_t_test)
```

Here is an tested code on another dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import cross_validation

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)# adjust yourself
pca.fit(X_train)
X_t_train = pca.transform(X_train)
X_t_test = pca.transform(X_test)
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_t_train, y_train)
print 'score', clf.score(X_t_test, y_test)
print 'pred label', clf.predict(X_t_test)
```

Based on these references:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. `AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'fit_tranform'`

Comment: @mar, a typo, fit_transform. Sorry that I do not have the environment to test this code.

Comment: Now, how can I use it for test?

Comment: @mar, If your 'test' means prediction, you can just use `clf.predict(X)`. If you want to evaluate the performance of classification, you can use cross-validation as updated.

Comment: `ValueError: X.shape[1] = 784 should be equal to 2, the number of features at training time`, however I put `pca.fit(X_test)`

Comment: I am sorry that I think I write another bug, The last two line updated with the feature after the transformation rather than the raw.

Comment: It works by replacing `clf.predict(X_t_test)` and `clf.score(X_t_test, y_test)`, but the result is the same, ` score 0.318262411348
pred label [7 7 7 ..., 7 7 7]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87849/discussion-between-xing-wang-and-mar).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is http://scikit-learn.org/. It's a python library where you'll find PCA, SVM and other cool algorithms for Machine Learning. It has a good tutorial, but I recommend you follow this guy's http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/general_concepts.html . For your particular question, the SVM page of scikit-learn should suffice http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html.